# Is there a symbol for "very different from"?

Tags: inequality, notation

Is there a way to write that $a≪b$ or $a≫b$ with a single symbol between $a$ and $b$, as in $a∘b$?

Another non-concise way to write this would be $|a-b|≫0$.

Comment: this is a non-math notation. it is a heuristical notatio engeneers and physicists often use, it is a strongly context-dependant notation. in math you have to exactly define what you mean by "very different".

Comment: @Max Oh, I was fooled by the title of [this](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.htm).